# Playing audio in Java

Tags: java, swing, audio, directory, javasound

I'm trying to make a soundboard program that loads a sound into a button, and then plays the sound when the button is pressed. This is what I have so far -

```
package soundboard;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Soundboard {

JButton loadButton;
JFileChooser loadBox;
JButton clearButton;
JButton button1;
JButton button2;
JButton button3;
JButton button4;
JPanel mainsPanel;

int load;
Clip clip;
File one;
File two;
File three;
File four;


public void windowCreate() {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    mainsPanel = new JPanel();

    loadBox = new JFileChooser();//174
    loadBox.setSize(500,500);
    loadBox.setLocation(174,4);


    loadButton = new JButton("Load...");
    loadButton.setSize(80, 30);
    loadButton.setLocation(4, 4);
    loadButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        load = 1;
    });

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setSize(80, 30);
    clearButton.setLocation(92, 4);
    clearButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        System.out.println("Cleared");
    });


    button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.setSize(80, 80);
    button1.setLocation(4, 45);
    button1.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            one = loadBox.getSelectedFile();
            load = 0;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Debugging; " + one);
            try {
                AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(one);
                AudioFormat format = audio.getFormat();
                DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
                clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            }  

            catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                System.out.println("Err_Line");
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Err_IOException");
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
                System.out.println("Err_FileNotSupported");
            }

            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
        }
    });

    button2 = new JButton("2");
    button2.setSize(80, 80);
    button2.setLocation(92, 45);
    button2.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            two = loadBox.getSelectedFile();
            load = 0;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(two);
        }
    });

    button3 = new JButton("3");
    button3.setSize(80, 80);
    button3.setLocation(4, 133);
    button3.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            three = loadBox.getSelectedFile();
            load = 0;
        }
        else {

        }
    });

    button4 = new JButton("4");
    button4.setSize(80, 80);
    button4.setLocation(92, 133);
    button4.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            four = loadBox.getSelectedFile();
            load = 0;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(four);
        }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(loadButton);
    frame.add(clearButton);
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);
    frame.add(button3);
    frame.add(button4);
    frame.add(loadBox);
    frame.add(mainsPanel);

    frame.setSize(675,485);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Soundboard window = new Soundboard();
    window.windowCreate();

}


}
```

What I need, basically, is some way of playing the sound when "button1" is pressed, without bringing up an external window, without having to write a new method, and without having to go outside the action listener. Copy-paste this into a new project titled "Soundboard", and if you figure this out, please let me know.

Here's a test-sound to use - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3riImENY0zSMUItWkUtaUg1X3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not a duplicate - It's quite a bit different

Comment: Well, if you don't want to add the method from that other question to your code, all you have to do is copy and paste the other code in.

Comment: doesn't look a duplicate to me. Same subject, different questions.

Comment: I just tried taking code from the other question's answers - It didn't work.

Comment: Try the code in 'playing a clip' seen in the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Comment: *"This is for midi files only"*  'This' what, exactly?  Who are you replying to?  Add @APerson (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.  And in case you *were* replying to me, the code I linked to is most definitely for audio clips, not MIDI files.  There is code for both on the page, but I said to use the code for 'Playing a Clip' not 'Playing a MIDI Sequence'..

Comment: @AndrewThompson The code given is for MIDI files only, not WAV files. And the Playing a Clip code uses a midi - Midi files and Wave files are extremely different. If it plays a midi I doubt it plays a wav.

Comment: *"The code given is for MIDI files only,.."*  How could you think `"http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav"` is a ***ing MIDI?!?  But for pity's sake, try it with one of your own Wavs if you don't believe me.  And as an aside, I'm the [top answer provider for Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/topusers) as well as the author of the [info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) that contains both code samples.

Comment: It just started working :D :D :D thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.setSize(80, 80);
    button1.setLocation(4, 45);
    button1.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (load == 1){
            one = loadBox.getSelectedFile();
            load = 0;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(one);
            try {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                ais1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(one);
                clip.open(ais1);
            } 
            catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                System.out.println("Err_Lineunavailable");
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
                System.out.println("Err_FileNotSupported");
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Err_IOException");
            }
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
        }
    });
```

I fixed the code. The variables, clips and all are declared public, outside of the methods, in order to make them public.

Thanks for your comments!